# ¿Qué es un "Magister Scientiarum en Ciencias"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, venezuela, lenguaje-académico

Acabo de leer un currículum vítae de un venezolano que indica el siguente título académico: "Magister Scientiarum en Ciencias".  ¿Qué es exactamente? ¿Cuál sería su equivalente en inglés?  Presumo que sería equivalente a un "Master's Degree", pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Los títulos académicos no tienen equivalencias en idiomas en sí, si no en países, ya que cada país tiene su propio sistema académico.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I had never heard *Magister Scientiarum* in Spain, but I guess it is the equivalent to `Master of Science` or `MSc` in English, at least is what it is called in UK...

See [MSc article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Science) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

*Magister Scientiarum* es una Maestría normal, nada más. Es el término en latín para designar ese nivel de estudios.

No es un Doctorado o PhD.

En castellano y en Lat Am se suele usar MBA (Master in Bussines Administration) para referirse a todas las Maestrías, lo cual es un error, una Maestria en Ciencias tiende a ser específica en la materia que enseñó en grado de Maestro. Por ejemplo, Magister Scientiarum en Administración sería el equivalente de MBA en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente en España no se ha usado nunca. Por lo que leo en los enlaces, al menos en parte de Sudamérica es el equivalente a nuestro título de doctor. La expresión más cercana a esto son los «títulos de máster», que se han puesto de moda con el Plan Bolonia, aunque «máster» deriva en este caso del inglés y no directamente del latín, pero se emplea «máster en» y nunca  «magister en», ni siquiera lo que se debería usar en castellano,  que sería «maestría en».

En cualquier caso, respecto al título citado, debería ser «*Magister Scientiarum*» a secas o especificar a qué ciencia se refiere, como dice Jose María, porque  «Magister *scientiarum* en ciencias» es una redundancia bastante evidente.

Sería como decir «Sobresaliente *cum laude* con alabanzas». ¿Verdad?

Especificando a qué ciencia se refiere ya es (más o menos) comprensible que el latinajo es sólo un título académico y lo que sigue en español es el tipo de estudios realizado, aunque quedaría mucho mejor con algunas palabras adicionales aclaratorias (algo como « Título de M. Sci. en ciencias políticas») o evitar totalmente la redundancia  usando «*Magister* en ciencias políticas», aunque así quede menos pomposo. O ya empeñados en usar el latín, no quedarse a medias y poner  «*Magister in politica scientia*» (esto ya es bastante pedante, y a lo peor ni es correcto, porque tengo muy olvidado el latín. Quedan avisados). `:)`

Comment: *Magister scientarium en ciencias* no es tan redundante como te parece, porque *scientia* significa algo como *conocimiento* (en castellano, *ciencia* en frases como *a ciencia cierta*).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Entiendo a lo que te refieres, pero precisamente es redundante porque significa «conocimiento». [Según la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ciencia) «ciencia» es un «conjunto de conocimientos», o un «saber» (sinónimo de «conocimiento»), o una «maestría» (para más redundancia en este caso). Evidentemente, según el contexto en que esté la palabra «ciencia» nos referimos un campo de estudio (doctrina científica) basado en el método que definió Francis Bacon, o a otra cosa, pero el significado siempre está relacionado con el «conocimiento».

Comment: Magister Scientiarum es equivalente una maestría estándar (MSc.) en Europa, no un doctorado.

Comment: @andandandand Y no he dicho otra cosa. He participado muchos años en cursos de doctorado y másteres en España, así que entiendo la diferencia. Solo dije que *me pareció* entender que en parte de Sudamérica sí es equivalente, sin afirmarlo categoricamente.

Comment: @Fran "Por lo que leo en los enlaces, al menos en parte de Sudamérica es el equivalente a nuestro título de doctor." Pues no tengo conocimiento de país alguno en Suramérica en el que una maestría sea equivalente a un doctorado español. ¿De qué enlaces hablas?

Comment: @andandandand Hace más de tres años de eso, pero si lo dije, es porque algo ví en ese sentido. Pero en fín, en España también nos vendieron hace ya mucho tiempo que los másteres serían no equivalentes, sino superiores,  y el doctorado cosa del pasado, y luego resultó de otro modo.

Answer (score 0):

Doctorate in Sciences equivalent to Ph.D

Answer (score 0):

Magister Scientiarum se abrevia como M. Sci. in "X" en tu caso M. Sci. in Science.

Véase [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Science) para la abreviación y un ejemplo del mismo postgrado en la [Open University de UK](http://www3.open.ac.uk/study/postgraduate/qualification/f12.htm)

Sin embargo tengo dudas con el uso de M. Sci. o M. Sc., parece que depende de los estudios, eso se explica [aquí](http://www.paperin.org/education/msci/MSci_degree_explanation), ya depende del *background* académico.

Answer (score 0):

*Magister Scientiarum* es el término en latin referente a *Maestro en Ciencias*. Supongo que el título completo de la persona del curriculum no lo has puesto completo ya que "Magister Scientiarum en Ciencias" debería ir seguido del campo específico en el que se ha graduado, por ejemplo:

"Magister Scientiarum en Ciencias Computacionales" o "Magister Scientiarum en Ciencias Políticas".

En Estados Unidos se utiliza en muchas universidades el término *Magister Scientiarum* directamente y es el equivalente directo de "Master of Science" lo cual concuerda con tu suposición inicial de que se trata de un *Master's Degree*.

Te dejo el link donde se explica este tema a detalle:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master's_degree

Answer (score 0):

Magister Scientiarum es Master of Science. En mi diploma recibido en Rusia se me otorga el grado científico de Magister Texnicheskix Nauk, que traducido es Master o Magister of Science in Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

"Requisito parcial para optar al grado de Magister Scientiarum"

Este titulo se le confiere en Venezuela, e imagino en muchos paises de America Hispana, a los graduados o que hayan aprobado estudios superiores a licenciatura, o ingeniera, se infiere que los titulos conferidos al culminar exitosamente tus primeros cinco años de nivel superior sea en medicina, artes, ingenieria, etc, te confieren el grado de Licenciado,Medico, Ingeniero, luego continuas con un post-grado- luego una maestria **(Magister Scientiarum)** - luego un PhD.o sea Doctorado - En Venezuela se le dice a los abogados y médicos al finalizar sus primeros 05 años "Doctores" mas por costumbre que por rango académico, ya que no tienen un PhD.

Answer (score 0):

Me pongo de ejemplo: soy venezolano, médico Cirujano de título medico humano. La carrera de Medicina en Venezuela es de 6 años + 1 año de rural (sin este último año no puede ejercer medicina). Luego realicé dos especialidades médicas de tres años cada una.

Al trabajo de investigación del grado de medicina se le llama trabajo especial de grado. Luego realicé una maestría Magister Scintiarum en Ciencias Veterinarias Mención Parasitologia y al trabajo de grado a este nivel se le llama trabajo de grado.
Luego de aquí se hace un doctorado y al trabajo de investigación se le llama trabajo de doctorado.

En mi caso me he quedado a nivel de maestría MSc, supongo que en España es master, no doctorado, porque el magister es 4.º nivel y el doctorado es de 5.º nivel.

Resumiendo:

1. Diploma de bachillerato
2. Estudios médicos, que culminan con título de grado
3. Especialidad, con su *trabajo especial de grado*
4. Maestría MSc, con su *trabajo de grado*
5. Doctorado, con su *trabajo de doctorado*
6. Postdoctorado PhD